# What is the sample space, outcomes, event space, random variables in machine learning?

Tags: probability, machine-learning

Reading through materials of *machine learning* problems, I see people treating things like they are doing with probability.

Particularly, consider linear regression. I cannot figure out what is the sample space, outcomes, events, random variables. In what manner they are using the word "probability measure" in the field of *machine learning*?

For instance, please take a look at [this](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-867-machine-learning-fall-2006/lecture-notes/lec5.pdf) article.

Moreover, in general, why do we need probability for machine learning? I don't see how we are going to calculate any probability of something in machine learning. While the need of linear algebra is obvious, since we are working on lists matrix of numbers. What properties of probability make it essential for machine learning?

Comment: you choose a model for your data/problem, then you search for an algorithm helpful for solving something in the context of this model. of course the model isn't chosen rigorously, it is just a model so that we can derive an algorithm rigorously from it. at the end, you see that choosing the model is the most important (and the least understood) step.

Answer (score 2):

Allow me to focus on your question "why do we need probability for machine learning?" as it seems to be the root of your confusion about why machine learning books make heavy use of probability theory. Consider what machine learning is all about - quoting [Tom Mitchell](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Etom/10701_sp11/):

> Machine Learning is concerned with computer programs that automatically improve their performance through experience.

There are two points in this quote which have probability hidden in the background. Consider the word "improve"; how would we know that a predictive algorithm has improved? One way is to find the probability that the predicted output matches the actual result - with more data, this is expected to increase. Now consider the word "experience"; a predictive algorithm can only learn from the data (experience) which it is given. This experience is usually modelled as a sample of some random variable. For example, imagine that we are interested in the relationship between some variable $X$ and another variable $Y$. We will have seen $n$ sample values for $X$ and $Y$ (the sample is the experience), then the algorithm uses that data to estimate how $X$ and $Y$ are related. What the algorithm learns is an estimator $p(X_{sample}, Y_{sample})$ of the joint probability function $P(X,Y)$. The sampling distribution of this estimator is important to know for a number of reasons. One of which is to tell us if the algorithm is consistent --- i.e. does $p(X_{sample},Y_{sample})$ converge to $P(X,Y)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, linear regression is used to model the relationship between input X and output/outcome Y.

**Outcome:** The y-value for each sample.

**Sample space:** all possible outcomes, which could be, like in the figure on the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) all real numbers or a subset of it. (Compare to a binary classification problem: Sample space {-1, 1})

**Event:** Everything you want to know a probability for. E.g. How likely is it to observe an outcome between 1 and 3?

**random variables:** X values.

I'm not sure if I understand "Why do we need probability for machine learning?". Maybe I haven't thought about it enough yet. For me probability is the point of machine learning.

You need probability to find out how "good" ore likely your model (classifier, regressor, ...) is. You need concepts like a probability distribution to make sense of data, to find out which features are actually useful (e.g. PCA) (not all problems have one input variable x and one output variable y, that would be way to nice!)

I used [this document](http://www2.edc.org/mathproblems/problems/printProblems/ekSampleSpace.pdf) and the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) for explanations.

Comment: You didn't mention that we use some models for the data, and usually those are probabilistic models. It allows us to use the maximum likelihood for estimating the parameters of our model. Unfortunately, even if the probabilistic model is simple, the ML estimator is often complicated. That's why often use a cost function and we don't specify any model for the data, but then it is hard to motivate why we use this cost function and not another one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to answer your question in the context of *computer vision*. An example would be image classification, where the labels of each image are mutually exclusive (one label per image). Lets say there are $n$ classes.

The input features are the image/s itself (which can be preprocessed in a multitude of ways such as rgb channel normalization, resizing, various data augmentation schemes etc.). The features are transformed through the convolutional layers of a backbone structure (such as VGG-$16$, Alexnet, or Resnet), and then fed through a Multi-Layer Perceptron to a Sigmoid layer to ultimately get a probability vector say $p$ with $n$ entries, one per class (sometimes $n+1$ for a background class, depending on if there are "empty" images).

During training, using a cross-entropy loss function, we compute for a single image (ignoring batching for now)

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} - g_{i} log(p_i)$ where $g_i$ is $1$ for an image with ground truth label $i$, and $0$ otherwise. As $p_i$ approaches $1$, we get a smaller loss, and hence a good prediction. As $p_i$ approaches $0$, we get a large loss, and hence a bad prediction. The network is *learning* to model the true probability distribution $p(Class_{i}|Image)$ which is $1$ for images with a classification label belonging to class $i$ and $0$ otherwise.

The optimizer (Stochastic Gradient Descent, Adam, etc.) then takes gradients of the model variables in the network that require gradient updates with respect to the loss, and updates the weights according to the optimizer algorithm.

For some other computer vision uses of probability...

In object detection, confidence scores (probabilities) are assigned to the detections that are output by a model, in addition to bounding boxes. This is done in order to threshold which detections will be evaluated in the computation of mean average precision or mean average recall, which are the evaluation metrics commonly used.

For a detection whose bounding box IOU is larger than some threshold, say $0.5$, for a given ground truth box with category label $c$, the model should learn to have high confidence values reflecting how certain the prediction is. The probability thresholds yield a trade-off between precision and recall. Set it too low? You will have a less precise model. Set it too high? You will miss predictions.

In semantic segmentation, for an image of size $(600, 600)$, with say $C$ classes (including the background), your model should get a feature map tensor of size $(600, 600, C)$ where by choosing at each pixel the channel value ($C$ value) that has maximal output, we choose which class the pixel belongs to for our inference prediction.